# Can't install Charles Proxy's CA certificate for the iPhone simulator

Tags: ios, ssl, proxy, charles-proxy

I've been using Charles Proxy for years now but i stopped working with the iPhone simulator when I upgraded to OSX 10.9 awhile back.

I followed the directions at http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/ssl-connections-from-within-iphone-applications/ and when I go to execute the downloaded shell script I get this:

```
Error: near line 1: column sha1 is not unique
```

(I don't know if that is a red herring or not.)

When I connect to my server I get this back from it:

```
SSL: Received close_notify during handshake
```

Months later I actually really need to get Charles Proxy working again so I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This worked for me: open the script and insert the following line
    `DELETE FROM "tsettings";`
below the line
    `sqlite3 "$SQLITEDBPATH" <<EOF`